# x-y = x+¬y+1 problem

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

I am currently reading a book about "bit fiddling" and the following formula appears:

```
x-y = x+¬y+1
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Example:

```
x = 0100  
y = 0010  
x-y = 0010  
¬y = 1101  
¬y+1 = 1110  
x+1110 = 10010
```

But `10010 != 0010...`

Where did I make a mistake (if any)?

(The book is "[Hacker's Delight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker%27s_Delight)" by Henry S. Warren.)

Comment: Note that this is not so much "bit fiddling" as it is ["the definition of subtraction"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You only have a four bit system!  That extra 1 on the left of your final result can't exist.  It should be:

```
x  = 0100
y  = 0010
~y = 1101
~y + 1 = 1110
x + 1110 = 0010
```

The other bit overflows, and isn't part of your result.  You may want to read up on [two's complement arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: Thank you very much :) Good explanation. Thanks to all others as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are carrying the extra bit.  In real computers if you overflow the word, the bit disappears.  (actually it gets saved in a carry flag.)  .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the numbers are constrained to 4 bits, then the fifth `1` would be truncated, leaving you with `0010`.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about overflow. You only have four bits, so it's not 10010, but 0010.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answers, in a 2's complement system:

```
~x + 1 = -x
```

Say `x = 2`. In 4 bits, that's `0010`.

```
~x = 1101
~x + 1 = 1110
```

And `1110` is -2